# ajax call works localhost but full page is returned on server asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax

My ajax call works in localhost but fails on remote server, instead the whole html page is returned with a 200 code.

Comment: would you like to share some code so that the problem can be solved?

Comment: presumably you can check in your console on the live system for script errors etc? JS not running (perhaps due to code not deployed properly, or not accessible due to permissions) sounds like the most likely explanation, but without any specifics including error messages or code samples we can only guess. Basically if it works in one environment and not another than you have to start playing spot the difference.

Comment: check your ajax call via browser network monitoring (e.g. F12) and check your ajax url

Comment: We do have additional components running on QA server - analytics, ask questions add on's etc, would these conflict?

Comment: I get a 200 returned, but with F12, I see the WHOLE page returned

Comment: yes you already said that. As I asked previously: when you first load the original page where the ajax call is run from, are there any javascript errors in the console? If you're getting a full page postback, but normally some JS would run to make the call, then that most likely indicates a JavaScript error which is then preventing the ajax call from happening, and instead the default postback behaviour occurs (probably the JS was taking steps to block the regular postback).

Comment: Since this appears to be a deployment issue, if you get any console errors (or errors in the network tab where JS files fail to load e.g. with a 404 or 403 error), check whether all your JS files etc were deployed successfully, and are accessible to the webserver. This is by far the most likely cause of what you're describing. Other components _could_ be a source of conflict if they integrate into the app and could cause JS errors, for instance. Best way is to check the console, pure and simple. Check at page load, and watch it carefully when you trigger whatever makes the ajax call.

Comment: on the ajax call in Network Tab, the code is 301

Comment: GetMyVauleAsJson:       Status: 301/       Type: Text/HTML

Comment: 301 indicates a redirection. an ajax call shouldn't ever return that really. Are you getting the 200 from the subsequent page load as well? Can you clarify? It's quite hard to really say anything more without seeing the relevant code, though.

Comment: Yes the page loads with a 200. Why would an ajax call return a 301?

Comment: because the server/code decided to. It'll be in the server code or config somewhere.

Comment: Thanks ADyson for your helpful answers, it transpired someone had put at 301 redirect on the asmx url by mistake so, for other readers:  if a 301 is returned on an AJAX request then always check the redirects set on on your web server as it's most likely there!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ADyson for your helpful answers, it transpired someone had put a 301 redirect on the asmx url by mistake so, for other readers: if a 301 is returned on an AJAX request then always check the redirects set on on your web server as it's most likely there!